# echo 'hello' vs echo "hello" vs echo hello, which should I use in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

Which characters should I use among {"", '',} when writing the **echo** command?

Obviously:

```
echo hello
```

```
echo "hello"
```

```
echo 'hello'
```

all three do not produce errors and perform what they should do, but I want to know which one is correct.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "hello"` ;)   It does not matter for your example which depends on personal preferences.  But there will be a difference when you want to expand variables.

Comment: Also worth a read: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Always use single quotes around every string or script unless you NEED double quotes (e.g. to let a variable like `"$PWD"` expand) or no quotes (e.g. to let wildcards like `*` expand to lists of files). Try `echo '$PWD *'` then `echo "$PWD *"` then `echo $PWD *`.

Comment: [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) is _very_ relevant to the places where this distinction matters (whereas in the cases where it doesn't matter, you don't have a narrow, specific problem you actually face so the question is off-topic).

Comment: Also potentially pertinent to people reading this is the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), since the excellent answer by Stephane goes into detail on the respects in which `echo`'s behavior is underdefined, unreliable, or nonportable -- important if anyone wants to understand the details of its behavior.

Comment: Of course they do  the same **for the concrete example** you have posted. In what respect would you expect them to be different? If you had written `foo=abc        def` (make sure you have plenty of spaces between _abc_ and _def_), and then do `echo $foo` vs. `echo "$foo"` vs. `echo '$foo'`, things would be much more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

All usages are correct. You must quote arguments that have spacing. For example

```
echo 'Hello  there'
```

can not be written without quotation marks, be it single or double, or escaping (see below). The main difference between single and double quotation marks is the processing of variables. Example:

```
w='World'
echo "Hello $w."
```

the second line requires double quotation or it will not print "Hello World." but "Hello $w.". HTH.

PS: You can escape spaces in the shell too, like this:

```
echo Hello\ \ there
```

and will leave the next one for you to guess how it works:

```
echo Hello\  there
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo hello` works for no spaces scenario, but it is not a good practice.

`echo "hello"` allow you to expand variables. For example:

```
V="Hello Guy!"

echo "MyVar: ${V}"
```

it produces:

`MyVar: Hello Guy!`

Instead, `echo 'hello` does not expand variables. For example, the latter example produces:

`MyVar: ${V}`